# Aria2c parallel download parameters

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, download, ftp, aria2

I am reading the Aria2c download manager [documentation](https://aria2.github.io/manual/en/html/aria2c.html) and some parameters seem redundant to me. For example:

> -x
>  The maximum number of connections to one server for each download. Default: 1
>
> -j 
> Set the maximum number of parallel downloads for every queue item. See also the --split option. Default: 5
>
> -s 
>  Download a file using N connections. ... Default: 5

From my pov, -x and -j/-s settings are contradicting. If -x is 1 and -j is 5, which takes priority? What is the combination of these three parameters I need to use to maximize one file download? download of multiple files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

-s: how many mirrors to use to download each file, mirrors should be listed in one line
-j: how many files (lines in the input file) to download simultaneously
-x: how many streams to use for downloading from each mirror.

So, if it is just one file, it goes like this:

```
aria2 -d ./ -x 10 "ftp://ftp.sra.ebi.ac.uk/vol1/fastq/ERR209/ERR209558/ERR209558_1.fastq.gz"
```

If you need to download a number of files, use `-i` to feed the input file, then go like this:

```
aria2 -d ./aria_dl/ -x 16 -j 16 -i ./aria_list_of_files.txt
```

That implies that you have only one link in each line, and `aria2` will use 16 streams for each of 16 files it is downloading. If you have multiple mirrors, put all mirrors for each file in one line and add `-s N`, where N is the maximum number of mirrors.

Answer (score 7):

I found the best way to download concurrently via aria2

```
`aria2c -c -s 16 -x 16 -k 1M -j 1 -i dl.txt`


-c, --continue [true|false]
-s, --split=<N>
-x, --max-connection-per-server=<NUM>
-k, --min-split-size=<SIZE>
-j, --max-concurrent-downloads=<N>
-i, --input-file=<FILE>
```

**NOTE:** Downloads the URLs listed in FILE. You can specify multiple sources for a single entity by putting multiple URLs on a single line separated by the  ***TAB*** and ***CR***(Enter) characters.

Comment: Mehrdad, the parameters that you provided turned out to be as you put it "the best way" to download files from a `txt` file. Thanks for sharing, doost-e man!